# Reading text values in a PowerPoint table using pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint

Using the pptx module,

```
 tbl.cell(3,3).text
```

is a writable, but not a readable attribute. Is there a way to just read the text in a PowerPoint table? I'm trying to avoid COM and pptx is a great module, but lacks this particular feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, you'll need to go a level deeper to get text out of a cell using python-pptx. The cell.text 'getter' is on the roadmap.

Something like this should get it done:

```
cell = tbl.cell(3, 3)
paragraphs = cell.textframe.paragraphs
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        print run.text
```

Let me know if you need more to go on.