# Update large amount of powerpoint files using python

Tags: python

I want to update some links contained in the slides of a large amount of powerpoint presentations. Instead of opening each presentation and copy / paste the correct links, is there a way to write a code with python?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think [this](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could do the trick.

Comment: Ya see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843018/read-from-powerpoint-table-in-python) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python library named `python-pptx` which works pretty fine and enables you to update your powerpoint presentations from python code.
You can find the documentation [here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-documentation).